Copy only *.log file
I have the below .ksh file. I just want to copy *.log file from parent_dir to target_dir while maintaining the folder structure and time stamp.
The below ksh copies EVERYTHING from source/parent_dir.
I just want *.log file copied.
#!/bin/ksh
# Input arguments
PARENT_DIR=$1
TARGET_DIR="/output/ndc_grid/target/folder/log_dump"

# Check if parent directory exists
if [ ! -d "$PARENT_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Parent directory $PARENT_DIR does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Check if target directory exists, if not create it
if [ ! -d "$TARGET_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Target directory $TARGET_DIR does not exist. Creating it..."
  mkdir -p "$TARGET_DIR"
fi

# Copy parent directory and its subdirectories to the target directory
echo "Copying parent directory and its subdirectories..."
#cp -r "$PARENT_DIR" "$TARGET_DIR"
find "$PARENT_DIR" -type f -name *.log -exec cp -pr {} "$PARENT_DIR" "$TARGET_DIR" \;
#find "$PARENT_DIR" -type f -name "*.log" -exec cp -pr {} "$TARGET_DIR/{}" \;

echo "Parent directory and its subdirectories have been copied to $TARGET_DIR"


your cp syntax is wrong. if you have rsync it's a one-liner

are the subdirectory copies also supposed to keep the same timestamps?

-name *.log is also risky and would break if your working directory contains files ending in .log. You need to quote it to avoid filename expansion by your shell.

Bsased on the last message in your script: Do you want to copy $PARENT_DIR to $TARGET_DIR or only the subdirectories and files?

Possible solution using cpio, assuming you don't have files with special characters in the name.
cd "$PARENT_DIR" && find . -type f -name "*.log" | cpio -pdmuv "$TARGET_DIR"

Omit cpio's option v if you don't want to see the list of processed files.
See man cpio for a description of the options.
